# django - HTML to PDF in Indian languages with pisa

Tags: django, pdf, pdf-generation, pisa

I'm converting a HTML file into PDF in Django using [Pisa](https://pypi.org/project/pisa/). It is working when the content is only in English. But here the content will be in English and five other Indian languages(Tamil, Hindi, Telugu, Malayalam, and Kannada). I have given my code below.

**views.py**

```
def render_to_pdf1(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context  = Context(context_dict)
    html     = template.render(context)
    result   = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf      = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result)
    return result.getvalue()

def print_pdf(request):
    message = Message.objects.get(id = 1)
    html_table_string = ''
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.english
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.tamil
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.hindi
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.telugu
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.kannada
    html_table_string += '%s' % message.malayalam

    fileread = str(settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS[0])+str('/base_file.html')
    fr = open(fileread, "r").read()
    fr = fr.replace('message_content', html_table_string)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    filewrite = str(settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS[0]) + str('/temp_file.html')
    empty = ""
    fw = open(filewrite, 'w')
    fw.write(empty)
    fw.write(fr)
    fw.close()
    pdf_contents     = render_to_pdf1('temp_file.html',result)
    file_to_be_saved = ContentFile(pdf_contents)
    name             = (str(request.user.email) + ".pdf").replace("@", '')
    pdf              = Pdf.objects.create(name = name, user = request.user, created_by = request.user)
    pdf.name.save(name ,file_to_be_saved)
    file_path = Pdf.objects.get(user = request.user).name
    pdf_file = str(file_path).split("media")[1]
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/site_media' + pdf_file)
```

Here what I'm doing is:

- Having a base template **base_file.html**.
- Getting the message object by ID (ID will be dynamically supplied).
- Then replacing the **message_content** with current content.
- Writing it in a file **temp_file.html**.
- Converting **temp_file.html** into a PDF file.

The converted PDF will be containing the message in English, Tamil, Hindi, Telugu, Kannada, and Malayalam. But I couldn't write the other language contents in the HTML file and couldn't convert it. The error I'm getting is `'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1066-1075: ordinal not in range(128)` and occurs in the line `fw.write(fr)`.

So how can I achieve this? I want to print the PDF file with content in all these languages.

Comment: Try fw.write(fr.encode('UTF-8'))

Comment: @Jeff Thanks Jeff. Its getting converted now without any errors. But now the problem is only black boxes are being displayed instead of other language text. I have given a sample [here](http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=8573). Please take look and give some suggestion to get it working. Thanks again.

Comment: Based on another stack overflow post you might need to add the second encoding bit after result: pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8').

If that doesn't help the only thing I can think off is ensuring that the font used has unicode support and checking whether it is referenced correctly.

Comment: I have tried that one also Jeff. pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8'). But it is not working. I'm translating the text using google translation api and so i couldn't find the font of the text. I'm giving a sample tamil text here. பிறந்தநாள் வாழ்த்துகள் How to find this font and how to reference it in pisa? I couldn't understand the steps given in documentation in reportlabs.com. Thanks in advance.